# Ternary condition in ng-click angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

In `HTML` I have a `button` and I am using `ng-click` event on it, like this:

```
ng-click="!user.name : openModel('lg') ? ''"
```

I am saying if `user.name` is not defined then call the function called `openModel()` else do nothing.

But it is generating the error

```
Error: $parse:syntax
Syntax Error

Syntax Error: Token ':' is an unexpected token at column 33 of the expression [!user.name :] starting at [{4}].
```

So what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax would be `ng-click="!user.name ? openModel('lg') : angular.noop()"`. `angular.noop()` is a function that peforms no operations.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't put any Condition Expression in Template.** Do it in the controller code,

```
ng-click="openModel('lg')"
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.openModel = function(value) {
    if ($scope.name) {
       Open();
    }
}
```